# Why does newer version of mocha not output test details when I run npm test?

Tags: node.js, npm, mocha.js

I have the following `devDependencies` specified for my project:

```
"mocha": "^3.4.2",
"mocha-sinon": "^2.0.0",
"sinon": "^2.3.7",
```

When I run my tests with these, I get only minimal output:

```
$ npm test

  Basic test example.
    simple test examples
```

When I downgrade the mocha dependencies to these versions:

```
"mocha": "^3.2.0",
"mocha-sinon": "^1.1.6",
"sinon": "^1.17.7",
```

I get the expected detailed output:

```
$ npm test

  Basic test example.
    simple test examples
      - expects more tests in future.

  2 passing (27ms)
  1 pending
```

Everything else is the same. I've fiddled with some of the mocha command line options without effect.

How do I get the detailed output with the newer version?

Comment: Are you by any chance using a third-party reporter with mocha or just the default `spec` reporter ?

Comment: @Bulkan Default. I tried some [others](https://mochajs.org/#reporters) but got similarly stingy output.

Comment: I can't reproduce this. What does `scripts.test` (in `package.json`) look like? Does it happen when you run `mocha` from the command line?

Comment: @robertklep `mocha --compilers js:babel-core/register ./test/test*.js`. Source can be found [here](https://github.com/chapmanu/omni-nav/blob/676ea05b/package.json). Yes happens when `mocha` is run. I thought it was originally something with the Node env on my Mac. But I reproduced the results from question on different Ubuntu system.

Comment: Still can't reproduce, so it might have to do with your Babel setup. Can you add the contents of `.babelrc` (or the relevant part of `package.json`) to your question?

Comment: The full source is at [that commit](https://github.com/chapmanu/omni-nav/tree/676ea05b61): [.babelrc](https://github.com/chapmanu/omni-nav/blob/676ea05b6125bdb63d4059074833295d76c11d11/.babelrc). As noted, if I downgrade mocha libraries, tests run as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're stubbing `console.log()` ([here](https://github.com/chapmanu/omni-nav/blob/676ea05b6125bdb63d4059074833295d76c11d11/test/test.js#L11)), which is what most (all?) Mocha reporters use to log their output (perhaps this changed between Mocha versions, which could explain why it worked with older versions).

Since you're stubbing it, it basically gets replaced by a function that does nothing, apart from tracking how it gets called, and with what arguments.

I'm not sure what your intentions are (the test file seems to be a placeholder), but to solve the problem try *spying* on it instead:

```
this.sinon.spy(console, 'log');
```

A spy will do the same tracking, but will also call the original function it's spying on.